# Can I link an entry to an Assets folder, instead of adding files?

Tags: assets, files

I am using Assets to manage documents associated with entries, but each entry will have sub-folders. Categories for each document. I am hoping to show a folder navigation on the front end to click the sub-folder, then even another, then list files.

I can create the folder hierarchy in Assets.

But instead of uploading/linking files to an entry, all I need to do is link the Assets folder. Can I do this in Assets?

The only way I can think of is make sure to name the folders the same as the entry url title so we can grab the correct folder, but thats open to mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a solution, so I wrote a fieldtype that allows linking an entry to an Assets folder. You can now create multiple folders and sub-folders, then link an entry to different parent folders, then using Asset tags retrieve the sub-folder list based on the entry's asset folder id.

https://github.com/amityweb/assets_folder